# Ifnull on subquery returns...NULL

Tags: mysql, sql

Any ideas why this subquery returns `NULL` when I'm expecting a `0` on `NULL` values:

```
SELECT
  (SELECT ifnull(visit.timestamp, 0) AS ifnull_1
   FROM keyword
   WHERE visit.keyword_id = keyword.id
   ORDER BY visit.timestamp DESC LIMIT 1) AS keyword_last_visit
FROM keyword
LEFT OUTER JOIN visit ON visit.keyword_id = keyword.id
```

`keyword_last_visit` returns always `NULL`

Comment: You dont have a ifnull on keyord last visit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should be used on the outer query..

```
SELECT
  ifnull((SELECT ifnull(visit.timestamp, 0) AS ifnull_1
   FROM keyword
   WHERE visit.keyword_id = keyword.id
   ORDER BY visit.timestamp DESC LIMIT 1), 0) AS keyword_last_visit
FROM keyword
LEFT OUTER JOIN visit ON visit.keyword_id = keyword.id
```

Comment: that's it, I suppose I don't need the first ifnull now do I?

Answer (score 1):

Try this with `CASE`

```
SELECT 
(SELECT (CASE WHEN visit.timestamp IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE visit.timestamp END) AS ifnull_1
   FROM keyword
   WHERE visit.keyword_id = keyword.id
   ORDER BY visit.timestamp DESC LIMIT 1) AS keyword_last_visit
FROM keyword
LEFT OUTER JOIN visit ON visit.keyword_id = keyword.id
```